# How do I download org customizations?

Tags: backup

I know I can download the metadata files using SFDX and VS Code. This will get me all of the classes, triggers, etc., from an org. I know I can then make local changes and deploy to the connected org.

But what about non-code changes to an org. What about the custom objects, process flows, tabs, etc. Is there a way to get all of this backed up to my local system as well and, if I wanted to, start with a new clean org and restore all the customizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't back up *all* your customizations, but you can back up *most* of your customizations. See the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/) for what's allowed and what's not. You can indeed back up custom objects and fields, some field customizations for standard fields (e.g. picklist values), flows, processes, workflow rules, validation rules, page layouts, tabs, custom apps, etc. It is possible to back up the vast majority of customizations and then recreate these customizations in a new org (either a Sandbox, new Production org, or a Scratch Org).

Comment: Your answer lead me down a path that eventually showed me how to download all the metadata, but I don't yet see a way to only download customizations. By including all of the potential types in my manifest file, I got everything, including the customizations, but I don't need the default layouts, for example, only the ones I've changed or created. Is that possible (without manually excluding metadata in `.forceignore`)?

Comment: @Chuck Not in an "untracked" org. Scratch Orgs can do this easily, but it's hard to identify "your changes" versus "default" (which can vary from org to org, and are typically necessary if you've added any custom fields). Once you've downloaded the files, you can delete what you don't want afterwards.